# How to make this box responsive?

Tags: html, css

I was building two boxes and wanted to make the second box responsive just like the green box on http://de.learnlayout.com/display.html . I was trying to achieve that by using `width: 100%` but this didn't work for me like in the example.

Heres my HTML code:

```
<body>

    <header>

        <div id="rand1">

            <div id="randelement1a">text</div>

            <p id="text1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr</p>

            <div id="randelement1b">text</div>

        </div>

        <div class="platzhalter"></div>

        <div id="rand2">

            <div id="randelement2a">text</div>

            <p id="text2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr</p>

            <div id="randelement2b">text</div>

        </div>

    </header>

</body>
```

and the CSS file:

```
#rand1 {
position: relative;                
width: 500px;
height: 112px;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 3px;
border-color: #0aa699;
}

#randelement1a {
position: absolute;                 
left: 0;
top: 0;
display: inline;                 
background-color: #0aa699;
}

#text1 {
position: absolute;
top: 20px;
}

#randelement1b {
position: absolute;                
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
display: inline;
background-color: #0aa699;
}

/*RESPONSIVE:*/

#rand2 {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 112px;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 3px;
border-color: #0aa699;
}

#randelement2a {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
display: inline;
background-color: #0aa699;
}

#text2 {
position: absolute;
top: 20px;
}

#randelement2b {
position: absolute;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
display: inline;
background-color: #0aa699;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolute positioning tends to not be your friend with responsive web design as it takes elements out of the normal document flow. On learnlayout.com you'll notice that the DIV you're referencing does not use `position: absolute;`. It uses `position: relative;` to contain the two absolute positioned `<span>` elements that contain `<div>`. Other than that it has a green border applied to it.

You're also setting a specific height on your DIVs which tends to defeat the purpose of responsive design. Your content will overflow the boundaries if there is not enough room when a height is set instead of the containing element re-sizing/re-shaping itself to the content.

I also see that you are using a bunch of IDs. That is a bit of a no-no. Use them sparingly and for JavaScript hooks. Use re-usable CSS classes instead, the ones that start with a `.`.

So, the solution is to:

- Remove the absolute positioning from your responsive elements like `<p>`.
- Remove height values from the containing DIVs (`#rand1`, `#rand1`) so they can *reflow* their content properly.

Here is a version of your code using CSS classes instead of IDs. As you can see it requires a lot less code. I also updated the first DIV with `max-width: 500px` so it can be responsive under `500px` in width instead of always being stuck at `500px`.

```html
<header>
    <div class="text-box fixed-width">
        <span class="text-box-label upper-right-label">text</span>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed
            diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna
            aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et
            justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no 
            sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem 
            ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr
        </p>
        <span class="text-box-label lower-left-label">text</span>
    </div>
    <div class="platzhalter"></div>
    <div class="text-box">
        <span class="text-box-label upper-right-label">text</span>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed
            diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna
            aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et
            justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no 
            sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem 
            ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr
        </p>
        <span class="text-box-label lower-left-label">text</span>
    </div>
</header>
```

```css
.text-box {
  position: relative;
  border: 3px solid #0aa699;
}
.fixed-width {
  max-width: 500px;
}
.text-box-label {
  position: absolute;      
  background-color: #0aa699;
}
.upper-right-label {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.lower-left-label {
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.text-box p {
  margin: 1.5em 2.5em;
}
```

Demo [JSFiddel using CSS classes](https://jsfiddle.net/xg5d6jpb/1/).

Demo [JSFiddle using CSS IDs](https://jsfiddle.net/xg5d6jpb/).

Comment: how should I write the code if I want the second box have the same width than the first box, plus only if the browser is smaller than this width then the second box will be responsively adjusted?

Comment: @Johnny the answer to that question is already in the post. _Hint:_ look at how the first box's width is controlled as it's already doing what you want to do for the second box.

Answer (score 0):

Try by changing the responsive element #rand2 height to `height: 100%;`and #text2 position to `position: relative;`